# Possibility of opening an extension within another extension in Autodesk Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

Is it possible to open a custom extension thorough another custom extension ?

I tried but I get issues at the time of "**Autodesk.Viewing.UI.DockingPanel.call**" not sure whether I have done it properly or it is possible at all .

My use case :

I need to create a report, which contains some additional data that needed to enter at runtime plus a screenshot of the current view.( for this i have one extension).

Above extension need to open through markup extension so I can add annotation and save the screenshot.
Cheers

**edit**

is it possible to add a custom extension to a core extension as well ?

```js
viewer.loadExtension("Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsGui").then(function (extension_)
{
    viewer.loadExtension('CreateNcrExtension');
});
```

This actually doesn't work . No error but wont load as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading extensions from another extension is common, and usually done in your extension's `load` method. The `load` and `unload` methods can be async, so you can do something like this:

```js
class MyAwesomeExtension extends Autodesk.Viewing.Extension {
    // ...
    async load() {
        await this.viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore');
        return true;
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to add custom extension into a core extension ? 

this is what I tried 

viewer.loadExtension("Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsGui").then(function (extension_) {
    viewer.loadExtension('CreateNcrExtension');
});


I have updated the OP as well

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "adding extension into" another extension? It would also help to provide more details about what the `CreateNcrExtension` is supposed to be doing.

Comment: Btw. if your extension is supposed to create a new type of markup, I'm putting together a blog post on how that can be done. There are some intricacies (for example, you cannot derive from the MarkupsCore classes until you load the MarkupsCore extension) that I will address as well.

Comment: Sure , I mean I have a custom extension called **CreateNcrExtension**, which basically open ups a small dialog box  ( using a panel and hatml tags) and it creates a report in the system( including a snapshot) . So what I want to achieve is add annotations for to that screenshot. That is why I'm trying to load my custom extension through **MarkupsGui**. I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing is correct as well, was just trying out

Comment: Ah I see. Note that if you simply want to load some markups from an SVG, you need the `Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore` extension, not `Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsGui`. The GUI extension is really only used to add some basic HTML UI for creating new markups.

Comment: No actually I just really need some basic markups , i just could't wrap around how to get it work together , i tried loading a custom extension within another custom extension using following code 

``
viewer.loadExtension("MyExtension1").then(function (ext_) {
    viewer.loadExtension('MyExtension2').then(function (subExt_) {
   });
});
``
but it did not load properly